# WP7 - Strange behavior during Application Deactivation and Activation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, lifecycle, tombstoning

I'm experiencing some strange behavior that I can't seem to find any information on. When I navigate away from my application and then navigating back (e.g. by launching `BingMapsDirectionsTask` or simply locking and unlocking the device) the entire screen gets pushed upwards by ~1/4 of its height when its resumed.

I'm guessing this has to do with the way I handle the applications life cycle (or lack of) since my current `Application_Activated` and `Application_Deactivated` are code-free.

Here is a quick clip that demonstrates this mysterious behavior beacuse I can't really explain it any better that this.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWHJT59F000

I've created another default VS2010 Express project and it behaves the same way so I'm guessing alot of people have had the same issue.

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Not sure, but might this be because it is capturing the swipe from the unlock screen perhaps?

Comment: @samjudson thanks for answering. I doubt that is the cause. Starting a BingMapsDirectionsTask and going back (hardware back button) results in the same behavior and that doesn't involve any swiping. Only thing that doesn't push the screen is if I recieve a call or make a call directly from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be related, but I had a similar issue whereby Slider was not drawn correctly after orientation changes if the Thumb was all the way to Max. So I had to use this code in the orientation changed event.

```
        double val = slider1.Value;
        slider1.Value = 0;

        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += delegate
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            };
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => slider1.Value = val);
            };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Perhaps try setting a delayed action after onNavigatedTo and see if that affects the layout.